# Angular 2 - Can a pipe call a function inside another component? (The pipe is used inside the component)

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a basic pipe that filters a list of results.
But I need the pipe to call a function in my component while its filtering.

In short, I have a map with markers on it.
These markers need updating to mirror the filtered list of the pipe.

both the pipe and the map currently work but not in sync.

I was thinking, if I could get the pipe to call the component its in, then it could update the map.

**This is my basic pipe that just filters a list of results:**

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'mapFilter', 
  pure: true
})

export class MapFilter {
   transform(items, [searchTerms]) { 
      var term = searchTerms[0];  
      var town = searchTerms[2];
      var county = searchTerms[1];

      var filterByTown = false;
      var filterByCounty = false;  

      if(town !== "Filter by Town")
          filterByTown = true;      

      if(county !== "Filter by County")
          filterByCounty = true;

      //Filter options:
        if(!filterByTown && !filterByCounty){
            return items.filter(item => item.name.indexOf(term) !== -1);
        }

        if(filterByTown && !filterByCounty){
            var termResult = items.filter(item => item.name.indexOf(term) !== -1);
            return termResult.filter(item => item.town.indexOf(town) !== -1);
        }

        if(!filterByTown && filterByCounty){
            var termResult = items.filter(item => item.name.indexOf(term) !== -1);
            return termResult.filter(item => item.county.indexOf(county) !== -1);
        }

        if(filterByTown && filterByCounty){
            var termResult = items.filter(item => item.name.indexOf(term) !== -1);
            var townResult = termResult.filter(item => item.town.indexOf(town) !== -1);
            return townResult.filter(item => item.county.indexOf(county) !== -1);
        }    
  }
}
```

**This is the html for my filter:**

- How would I pass in the markers array for the map and would the map pick this up?
- I need to add **"this.markers"** to the below code

  ```
          <tr *ngFor="#item of jobs | mapFilter: [searchTerm, county, town]" class="animated fadeIn" (click)="viewJob(item)">
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a pipe is the proper tool for this use case. Create your filtered data in code and assign the result to a field and bind the view to this field.
The pipe would be tightly coupled to this one component anyway, so why not add the code to the component in the first place.

What you can do if you want pursuit your current approach is to pass additional arguments to the pipe like

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of jobs | mapFilter: [searchTerm, county, town, markers]" class="animated fadeIn" (click)="viewJob(item)">
```

The pipe is called again each time when marker changes.

Comment: Thanks, il try it. Do you think the map which is placed above the pipe will update?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "map which is placed above the pipe will update". I can't see a map, what is "above the map"?